# Why the consecutive spherical wavefronts produced by a rest point source are not equidistant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, waves, huygens-principle

I learnt that a point source produces spherical wavefronts and i know the reasoning behind that too and while studying the concept again a question popped in my mind, that "Are those spherical wavefronts equidistant ?", most online sources don't have an answer.
A clear explanation for the question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ChatGPT is not a source. It is a chat bot meant to mimic human speech and nothing more.

Comment: Welcome Logan to Physics SE. Please read ["Please don't use computer-generated text for questions or answers on Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14281/145491).

Comment: Try asking chatGPT again. I just asked "Are the wavefronts of a spherical wave equidistant?" It told me they are equidistant from the source. Correct, but not quite what I had in mind. I tried "Are the wavefronts of a spherical wave equidistant from each other?". It told me again they are equidistant from the source. You might get a better answer if you ask the right way. Or not.

Comment: We do have a policy that not to use chatGPT at this site. But make no mistake. ChatGPT is far more that a bot the mimics human speech. For programming questions it is excellent. It can write snippets of code, explain error messages, and provide documentation better than much of what you find online. A lot of effort has gone into making it helpful for programming. It isn't as good at physics. But in a few years, it will be.

Comment: This worked. "Is the distance between consecutive wavefronts of a spherical wave constant?"

Answer (score 1):

"As a result, the distance between consecutive spherical wavefronts increases as they move away from the source." This is a non sequitur; it doesn't follow from the previous sentence. Nor is it true. We usually draw wavefronts that are 1 wavelength apart, as measured along the propagation direction. Usually the propagation direction is at right angles to the wavefront at all points on the wavefront. In your case the propagation directions are along radii, so successive wavefronts are $\lambda$ apart, as measured along radii.

[The wavefronts *would* get further apart as they spread out from the source if the medium were inhomogeneous in such a way that the waves travelled faster the further they were from the source. But that would be weird. Alternatively the source frequency could be decreasing as time went on. Weirder still?]

Answer (score 0):

Both of your are right, because you and ChatGPT have different ideas of what the term "equidistant wavefront" means. For you, the point source does "doot doot doot" and the doots propagate along an axis. With "distance", you mean the distance between the doots. But ChatGPT means the distance in the plane of the first doot, which is perpendicular to the propagation direction, which indeed stretches apart. So both of you are correct, but in different contexts, because your distance (between the doots) stays the same, while the points on that plain of the first doot stretch apart as the wave propagates, because it is a sphere with an expanding radius.

Comment: Which of us is going to be first to bring out the book *Learn Physics by Doots*?

Comment: "But ChatGPT means the distance in the plane of the first doot, which is perpendicular to the propagation direction, which indeed stretches apart" Sir i didn't got that. Can you please explain that.

Comment: I, too, didn't understand what you mean by "the plane of the first doot". I thought that we were dealing with spherical wavelengths, so I don't see the relevance of planes.